# Safari Content Blocker Name Not Honored

Tags: macos, safari, macos-sierra

I am trying to write a Safari Content Blocker extension for macOS Sierra. ([Here is the source](https://github.com/wjk/AdBlockPlus-macOS), if it is helpful.) My extension is showing up in Safari’s Extensions pane as intended. However, it is sometimes referred to in the Extensions window using the name of the bundle (in my case, `SafariExtension.appex`). Other times it correctly uses the localized `CFBundleDisplayName` as set in the `InfoPlist.strings` file. I have included a screenshot of the Preferences window while exhibiting this bug below, if it helps.

(I do not know how to force Safari to refresh this pane, either. If anyone could point this out, I would be very appreciative.)

[image: Safari Extensions Window]